# SQLAlchemy query using both ilike and contains as filters

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use both .contains and .ilike to filter a query from a string value.

For example the query should look something like this:

```
model.query.filter(model.column.contains.ilike("string").all()
```

Currently querying by .contains returns case sensitive results. And querying by ilike returns case unsensitive results, but the characters must match which is far too specific a query. I want potential results to appear to the user as they do with a .contains query.

Comment: Why not just `.ilike("%string%")` ?

Comment: @poz I did that. .ilike is only returning results if the string exactly matches the database item. For example.. if you type 'ant', the string should return all items in the database that begin with 'ant'. ilike only returns something if I type "antenna abcd" which is way too specific... i want all 'antennas' in the database to be returned if i type 'antenna'.

Comment: @poz oh ok. Didn't have the percentage signs. yea works now with those added. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

foo = model.query.filter(model.column.ilike("%"+ string_variable +"%")).all()